# Weld name and symbole notation

Tags: engineering

[image: Drawn examples: Thin sheet metal weld joints]

My questions are in regards to thin metal sheets. Are these weld joints standard in the industry? What weld type is preferred for thin metal sheets? What is the proper name and symbol notation for each weld shown?

Comment: this definitely isn't about cold-welding.  or engine design, I think

Comment: Doesn't seem like its on topic here, maybe in https://engineering.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @user28833 - can you please clarify the context around your question. What are you trying to understand, or work on? If you just want the names of types of welds, looking at a welding website is likely to be your best bet.

Comment: Perhaps this could be better phrased. Is it that you have a reason for believing that welds specifically for space might be done a particular way? That would be a starting point for this site, though it might be a bit down in the weeds too.

Comment: I don't know the industry standard practice for welding thin sheets in a particular way. I would have assumed each diagram in the figure is a possible welding option.